# How to send an email describing matrix contents in Matlab

Tags: matlab, email

I have a simple matrix such as the following:

```
A = [1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9];
```

What I would like to do is use the `sendmail`-function and receive the matrix in my email so that when I would open the message I would see it in the following way:

[image]

I have managed to get the sendmail-function to work, but I can't receive the matrix in the form I would like to. So far I see for example only one value in my mailbox from the matrix after trying out few tricks. Did I explain my problem clear enough? x)

In other words I want to see the table in my mailbox the same way as I would see it in Matlab. I have a program which is doing data-analysis and what I want to do is leave the computer on to do the calculations and then send me the results in email when they're done.

So my question is: "How to set up the matrix for the `sendmail`-function, so that I get the desired results in my email as I described above?"

Hope my question is clear. Thnx for any assistance.

P.S. could I for example break this matrix into a matrix looking string somehow?

update:

here is some of my attempts:

```
% results contains my result matrix
mymes = '';
for i = size(results, 1)
    for j = 1:size(results, 2)
        mymes = [mymes ' ' num2str(results(i, j))];
    end
end

sendmail('myaddress@test.com', 'The results', mymes)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
mymes = evalc('disp(results)');
```

`disp` displays your matrix, as it would normally appear at the command line. `evalc` captures the command line output from a command, and stores it in a string, including newlines. You should be able to just email yourself that string.

Hope that helps!